# PHP-Redis, как установить для альтернативной версии PHP (8.0)?

Tags: php, redis, ispmanager

Возникла проблема с установкой php-redis для альтернативной версии php8.0, в нативной версии устанавливается без проблем. При установке на убунту незнаю почему но команда install php-redis загружает пакеты только для php8.1, а необходим php8.0 (у меня панель ISP)

Comment: А вы пропобали добавить вашу версиб `php`? Пропробуйте вот так `install php8.0-redis`

Comment: говорит не найдена в библиотеке